# Trying to display filler text in form, but make it "hidden" to printer

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm having a tough time finishing a (protected) form in Word. It was printing out all of the filler text (e.g. "Click here to type," "Select Date") when users didn't enter any data. So, I changed the style/font for this text to "Hidden" as I had read to do on another forum.

Unfortunately, now every control (text box, drop down list, etc.) is basically invisible and the size of an n dash. :/  So no one can easily fill it out.

Anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That would need to be done with a macro that applied the hidden Font property on any control that was not altered from its default setting. This would have to be trapped in a DocumentBeforePrint event ... which has some other complications with distributable forms, meaning, the form would need to be macro enabled.

Comment: Yes, I was worried about that. Okay, thank you.